# React state gets reset to previous value between renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm updating state(an array) onClick of a button, everything works fine for all the elements in the state array except for the last one which when updated quickly reset the state to its old value.

```js
 <Button
      icon={<IconDeleteStroked />}
      type="danger"
      onClick={() => {
      Toast.success("Table deleted!");
      props.setTables((prev) => {
      return prev
           .filter((e) => e.id !== i)
           .map((e, idx) => ({ ...e, id: idx }));
      });
       setTableActiveKey("");
      }}
 ></Button>
```

`setTables` gets passed down from a parent component, and I'm tracking the `tables` by logging them in a `useEffect`
here you can see it get correctly updated to `[]` and then to `[{...}]`[screenshot of useEffect logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmGay.png)

I tried using `memo` and `useCallback`( ik it's only for optimization:') ) to avoid rerenders that might reset the state.

What might be causing the problem and how can it be fixed?

Thanks in advance:)

Edit (added a minimal reproducible example): [src](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-playground-practice-9z5xnc?file=index.js,package.json)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: added the link to the post :)

Comment: The reproducible example should be within the question itself, not a link to another site. It would also be much appreciated if you could format and indent your code nicely. I recommend running it through Prettier before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `<Form>` onChange is triggering when you click the delete button, and overwriting the deleted table update when it calls `props.setTables(updatedTables);`, since the references to `tables` in there doesn't know about the deleted table.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. it all works now. thank you very much:)

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, your question wasn't very clear, I had to guess at what your problem was. Also, for future questions, the smaller you can make the reproducible example, the better. It was not clear from your question what component(s) were involved in the problem. I suggest all newcomers check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which can help get faster answers in the future.